# Creating a new vector based on pair of levels in R or Excel

Tags: r, excel

Suppose I have an existing array that looks like

```
   [,1][,2]
[1,] a b
[2,] a b
[3,] a b
[4,] a c
[5,] a c
[6,] b c
[7,] b c
[8,] b a
[9,] a b
```

I wish to create a vector of numbers that gives an unique code to each pair. The code is not important, as long as it is unique for each pair, its okay.

For example 2 valid codes are

```
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 1
[1] 14 14 14 15 15 8 8 67 14
```

The data in which I am working on contains names as first column and dates (10-May-16 type of format) as 2nd column stored in Excel file.

Its okay if the solution is applicable to either R or Excel. Any help/suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can firstly create a factor variable based on the two columns then coerce it into numeric:

```
as.numeric(as.factor(paste(myMat[,1], myMat[,2])))

[1] 1 1 1 2 2 4 4 3 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the matrix is named `a`:

```
c(interaction(a[, 1], a[, 2]))
## [1] 3 3 3 5 5 6 6 2 3
```

**Note:**  For sake of reproduciblity, we used this as `a` :

```
a <- matrix(c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "a", "b"), 9, 2)
```

Comment: ...and `c(interaction(a[, 1], a[, 2], drop=TRUE, lex.order=TRUE))` if the ordering or starting at `1` were necessary.